# How to work multi input fields at once

Tags: javascript, java, html

I would like to disabled onchange by only defal4-disabl except (defalt1enabl,defalt2enabl,defal31enabl).

And work (enabled/disabled) both input fields at once?

Can any expert provide me modified Fiddle?

Comment: Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/rbwtq/346/

Comment: please rewrite your question. its terrible

Comment: Use a `class` rather than duplicating `ID`'s. **ID**'s should be unique.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I would like disabled with 2 input fields by clicking 'defal4-disabl' 

Snapshot: http://s20.postimg.org/8livbmtyl/screenshot_208.png

Comment: Maybe we can use different id? If yes, then how to use different ID in javascript. I have tried :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your updated fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/rbwtq/348/

This HTML:

```
<input name="test" type="text" id="disabled_input"/>
<br /><br />
<input name="test" type="text" id="disabled_input"/>
```

is changed to:

```
<input name="test" type="text" class="disabled_input"/>
<br /><br />
<input name="test" type="text" class="disabled_input"/>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
var defalt1enabl = $(this).val();
if(defalt1enabl == "defalt1enabl"){           
  $('#disabled_input').removeAttr('disabled');          
}
else{
  $('#disabled_input').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
}
```

is changed to this:

```
var selectedOption = $(this).val();
if(selectedOption == "defalt4-disabl"){     
  $('.disabled_input').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
else{
 $('.disabled_input').removeAttr('disabled'); 
}
```

Comment: Great, its working now :)

Would check one thing that i have sent different class. How work with different class. http://fiddle.jshell.net/rbwtq/350/

Comment: Check this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/rbwtq/354/

For different classes, you need to call the same function on both the classes.

Similarly, you can use different ids too.

Comment: Thanks understand. As i can see my 2 input fields with different select name, so with like the select names as facility & nonfacility, how to define both select names?

Comment: My code looks like this.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/rbwtq/366/

Fiddle with working file, but But in my html page with not working..

Comment: That's nice. 

Comment: Is it possible when click 'defal4-disabl' then hide both fields called Something, Something with keeping disabled?

Comment: Yeah! You can directly apply css on them via jquery and set `display: none`

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your piece of code as provided below.

**For HTML**:

`<input name="test" type="text" class="disabled_input"/>
<br /><br />
<input name="test" type="text" class="disabled_input"/>`

**For Script**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.disabled_input').attr('enabled','enabled');        
$('select[name="facility"]').on('change',function(){
var  defalt1enabl = $(this).val();
    if(defalt1enabl == "defalt1enabl"){           
    $('.disabled_input').removeAttr('disabled');          
     }

     else{
     $('.disabled_input').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
    }  

  });
});
```